# Exception configure fluent with MySQL

Tags: mysql, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to configure NHibernate to use a MySql database.
I use the following code:

```
_sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure().Database(
                MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(
                cs => cs.Server("localhost").Database("Schedule").Username("root").Password("root"))
                ).Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<NHibernateHelper>()).BuildSessionFactory();
```

and I have the following exception :

[image]

how to solve?

Comment: Does your database exist?  FluentNHibernate does NOT create databases.

Answer (score 1):

MySql ADO.NET driver dll is not in the directory of your program and also not installed. copy MySql.Data.dll into you program dir.